# Block/Restrict users not to call our webservices from outside our application

Tags: jquery, web-services, security

Let me go straight to the question.

we have a jquery based website say(http://www.mywebsite.com), and a set of webservices under the same domain like (http://www.mywebsite.com/services/service1.asmx).

Now, since it is jquery based application with ajax calls to the webservices, URLS of our webservices are exposed to the public through developer tools.

Is it possible that we can know if the web service is called only from within our application, otherwise dont execute it.

Your prompt response will be highly apprecaited.

Comment: U seem to need some authentication module??

Answer (score 0):

I AM NOT A CRYPTO EXPERT, THIS IS JUST WHAT I HAVE DONE IN THE PAST.

Since your application is not actually called from 'within your application' but within the client's browser there is no way for you to identify the validitiy of your calls, out of the box.

What I usually do is to have some means of recognizing the valid user.

Say the user logs in, or he may just be landing on your index. What you do, is you generate a token - a hash. Your server knows what rules apply for this token, but an eager hacker/cracker does not.

Let's say you generate a session_id = 1q2w3e (please use something longer and find some rules that's hard for external observers to guess. For instance you could create a hash from the clients IP based on a secret/salt [ [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) ] only you know).

Now, for each succeeding call into your API, make it mandatory that the session_id is a part of the request. Then, for each call, authorize that hash to check that it's valid. If it is, continue with the call.

Beware, that if you're not on HTTPs, surveillance of the network can allow crackers to 'session hijack' by observing the session_id, and use that for his future calls.

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thanks for your response.

I have also done the same thing for all those pages which are executed after the user logs in.

But my problem is that I have few pages that do not even require to login and hence I do not have any session available on the client, like user registration page.

Comment: the user registration page should then only call into parts of your API which is OK for all to access. You could have your server embed a session ID in your html, and use that as session_id just to make it more likely that they are calling into your API through your site. Does it makes sense to you? You would be creating a session_id that's not directly tied to a user, but rather to those visiting one of your public pages.